# machine epsilon - long double in c++

Tags: c++, epsilon, long-double

I wanted to calculate the machine Epsilon, the smallest possible number `e` that gives `1 + e > 1` using different data types of C++: `float`, `double` and `long double`.

Here's my code:

```
#include <cstdio>

template<typename T>
T machineeps() {

  T epsilon = 1;
  T expression;

  do {
    epsilon = epsilon / 2;
    expression = 1 + epsilon;
  } while(expression > 1);

  return epsilon;
}

int main() {
  auto epsf = machineeps<float>();
  auto epsd = machineeps<double>();
  auto epsld = machineeps<long double>();

  std::printf("epsilon float: %22.17e\nepsilon double: %22.17e\nepsilon long double: %Le\n", epsf, epsd, epsld);

  return 0;
}
```

But I get this strange output:

```
epsilon float: 5.96046447753906250e-008
epsilon double: 1.11022302462515650e-016
epsilon long double: -0.000000e+000
```

The values for `float` and `double` are what I was expecting, but, I cannot explain the `long double` behavior.

Can somebody tell me what went wrong?

Comment: Is it for the sake of practice, or are you unaware of [`std::numeric_limits::epsilon`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon)?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `...epsilon long double: 5.421011e-20`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the behavior of this code depends on the rounding mode set on your environment, it's thus fairly broken anyways.

Comment: Try to output the binary or hex representation of those variables' bytes instead, I'm halfway sure outputting does some kind of rounding. Concerning the mentioned numeric limits, try outputting those for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your results. I get:

> epsilon long double: 5.421011e-20

Anyway, logically, the code should be something like:

```
template<typename T>
T machineeps() {
  T epsilon = 1, prev;
  T expression;

  do {

    prev = epsilon;
    epsilon = epsilon / 2;
    expression = 1 + epsilon;

  } while (expression > 1);

  return prev;  // <-- `1+prev` yields a result different from one
}
```

On my platform it produces values similar to `std::numeric_limits::epsilon`:

> epsilon float: 1.19209289550781250e-07
>
> epsilon double: 2.22044604925031308e-16
>
> epsilon long double: 1.084202e-19

(note the different order of magnitude)

Answer (score 0):

There are several things going on here.

First, floating-point math is often done at the maximum available precision, regardless of the actual declared type of the floating-point variable. So, for example, arithmetic on `float`s is usually done with 80 bits of precision on Intel hardware (Java originally banned this, requiring all floating-point math to be done at the exact precision of the type; this killed floating-point performance, and they quickly abandoned that rule). Storing the result of a floating-point calculation is supposed to truncate the value to the appropriate type, but by default most compilers ignore this. You can tell your compiler not to allow that; the switch for that depends on the compiler. As is, you can’t rely on the result that’s being calculated here.

Second, the loop in the code terminates when the value of `1 + epsilon` is **not** greater than 1, so the returned value will be **less than** the true value of epsilon.

Third, coupled with the second one, some floating-point implementations don’t do subnormal values; once the exponent becomes smaller than the smallest that can be represented, the value is 0. That may be what you’re seeing here with the `long double` value. IEEE floating-point handles zeros less abruptly — once you hit that minimum exponent, smaller values gradually lose precision. There are quite a few values between the smallest normalized value and 0.